# Select parts of my code have been greyed out

Tags: python, visual-studio, syntax-error

I wrote a while loop asking the user whether they're male or female. Everything after "else" has been greyed out. When I hover over it with my mouse it says:

"Code is unreachable  Pylance".

```
sex = input('What is your sex? (m/f/prefer not to say) ')
while True:
    sex = input('What is your sex? (m/f/prefer not to say' )
    print('success:)')
else:
    print("sorry doll, I can't help you:( let's try again.")

print("we're out of the loop")
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: thats because it is an infinite loop. as your condition would always be true

Comment: How do I change the loop to end when the user writes "m" or "f"?

Comment: `while sex not in ("m", "f")` or `while sex != "m" and sex != "f"`

Comment: Works. Thank you sm!

Answer (score 0):

Note the differences. the break exit the loop totally.
The while loop continues operation as long as it condition evaluates as True. so therefore you need to create condition to either break from the loop within your code or modify the loop to evaluate as false.
Also, you would realise that when the loop eventually turns false only then is the else statement called. However, the else wont be called if break keyword was used to exit the loop.

```
tries = 5
opt =('m','f','prefer not to say')
while tries:      #evaluates True but false if tries = 0
    sex = input('What is your sex? (m/f/prefer not to say' ).lower()
    if sex not in opt:
        print("sorry doll, I can't help you:( let's try again.")
        tries -=1
        continue
    print('success:)')
    tries=0 # note here the bool(0) == False
    
else:
    print('happens if there is no break from the loop')
    
print("we're out of the loop")

#opt 2
while True:
    sex = input('What is your sex? (m/f/prefer not to say' ).lower()
    if sex not in opt:
        print("sorry doll, I can't help you:( let's try again.")
        continue
    print('success:)')
    break. # completely exits the loop
else:
    print("sorry doll, I can't help you:( let's try again.")

print("we're out of the loop")
```